# How to detect the perfect Shoulder Center Position using Kinect?

Tags: c#, xna, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am trying to detect the shoulderCenter Position of a Skeleton.  I have used the following code to get the skeleton center position and place a Cloth image on it. The problem i am facing is that its not placing the Cloth image on the center of the Skeleton and i have to add more values in order to place the Cloth in the center of the skeleton.

The problem isn't done yet. After adding some values, It works fine on my body. I am 5'6", but if a 6ft skeleton comes in, the cloth image does't come to its Center, and i have to add more values to SKeletonCenter Value to place the cloth image perfectly on 6ft skeleton. And after adding these values it won't work fine for 5'6" skeleton.

Since i have to add different values for different skeleton, which is very annoying and not practically possible.

I know i am doing something wrong in getting the Skeleton Center Position,Kindly tell me an appropriate way of doing this.

```
              origin = new Vector2(currentShirt.Width / 2,0);


     if (shoulderCenter.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
                            {

                                //SHOULDER Center
                                shoulderCenterPos = sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(shoulderCenter.Position, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);

                                shirtXposition = shoulderCenterPos.X;// -180;
                                shirtYposition = shoulderCenterPos.Y;// +20; 
            }

    //Draw Method
    //If i dont add these values in ShirtXposition and ShirtYPosition it would place shirt somewhere in the top.

    //CustomShirtWidth=300
    //CustomShirtHeight= 550


   spriteBatch.Draw(currentShirt, new Rectangle((int)(shirtXposition)-90, (int)(shirtYposition)+240, (int)(customShirtWidth), (int)(customShirtHeight)),Color.White);
```

**EDIT**
//For Height and Width I am using this.
The problem with this is that, its constantly changing the size of the image, and when i assign it to a constant variable it gives me an error message.

```
                DepthImagePoint rightShoulderPt = sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(rightShoulder.Position, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);
                DepthImagePoint leftShoulderPt = sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(leftShoulder.Position, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);

                float totalWidth = rightShoulderPt.X - leftShoulderPt.X;
                float totalHeight = Head.Position.Y - hipsCenter.Position.Y;
```

Comment: You add X and Y in `shoulderCenterPos.X + shoulderCenterPos.Y`. Is that wise? Could you maybe describe in text instead of code what all the variables mean and why you use the calculations you use?

Comment: Thanks for the reply..Are You talking about `shoulderCenterPoint`. I mistakenly add this here. I am not using it anywhere else.\

Comment: I have updated the code, Kindly check it again..This Code is working fine for 5'6" skeleton but it won't work fine for any other skeleton.

Comment: Can't you just measure the correct width and height in the skeleton (height probably from hip to shoulder center, width from left shoulder to right shoulder). Then use a constant multiple of these values to add to your coordinates.

Comment: I have updated my code, Kindly check it..The Width and Height constantly changing when i use it..Can you please tell me how to save these values in a constant variable.